# Error Message: int' object is not callable

Tags: python

I am trying to create a game, in which the user is prompted for a value between 1 to a 100.

I'm getting the error message `Error Message: int' object is not callable`

```
# Taking Inputs
value = int(input("Enter an value between 1 and 100"))
 
# Defining target
target = int(74)
 
# Process of guessing
while value != target:
 
    # Condition testing
    if value == target:
        print("Bingo!")
        # Once guessed, loop will break
        break
    elif value > target:
        print("You guessed too large!")
    elif value < target:
        print("You guessed too small!")
```

Comment: change to  `# Defining target
target = 74`

Answer (score 0):

```
value = int(input("Enter an value between 1 and 100:"))
target = int(74)
while value != target:
    # Condition testing
    if value > target:
        print("You guessed too large!")
    elif value < target:
        print("You guessed too small!")
    value = int(input("Enter an value between 1 and 100:"))
else:
    print("Bingo!")
```